# Can NGINX inspect the TLS request to look for SNI like HAProxy (etc) does?

Tags: nginx, https, haproxy, tls, sni

It seems that, when configuring HAProxy for hostname routing on HTTPS connections, it is crucial to include a `tcp-request inspect-delay` directive to "give HAProxy a chance to look into the connection". Is there a way to get NGINX to to the same, or should I start packing it up and move my whole server to HAProxy?

(For reference, this question comes from my previous misunderstanding expressed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/778211/does-nginx-support-sni-or-does-it-not))

**EDIT**

Michael, in the comments:

> he seems to want to "sniff" SNI from the client's handshake attempt without actually terminating the TLS connection, in order to make a lower-layer connection-proxying decision and blindly carry the payload to a subsequent machine for termination of the TLS, because for some reason he doesn't want the TLS certs and keys on the proxy, or for the proxy to do the TLS at all -- just sniff the SNI and make an inward TCP connection using a rule derived from its content.

The rationale is that I need the certificates and keys within the backend applications (some require this for one reason or another), so I have to provide these to them. Having to set them up in the proxy too essentially doubles the maintenance work, and the chance for error. If I could do without maintaining access to the certificates for the proxy, it would make my architecture much easier, and lessen the chances for mistakes.

Comment: What's your problem, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tim based on the other question, he seems to want to "sniff" SNI from the client's handshake attempt  without actually terminating the TLS connection, in order to make a lower-layer connection-proxying decision and blindly carry the payload to a subsequent machine for termination of the TLS, because for some reason he doesn't want the TLS certs and keys on the proxy, or for the proxy to do the TLS at all -- just sniff the SNI and make an inward TCP connection using a rule derived from its content.  The rationale isn't as clear to me as is the desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's exactly what I want to achieve. The rationale is that I need the certificates and keys within the backend applications (some require this for one reason or another), so I have to provide these to them. Having to set them up in the proxy too essentially doubles the maintenance work, and the chance for error. If I could do without maintaining access to the certificates for the proxy, it would make my architecture much easier, and lessen the chances for mistakes.

Comment: Hello! I got into this question looking for other stuff and I think I have something of your interest. If you still interested :-P. At the bottom of: https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html you have a variable $ssl_server_name that "returns the server name requested through SNI"

Comment: @Morpheu5 did you end up reaching a solution for this? I have a similar use case

Comment: @Chris I ended up terminating the TLS connection at the proxy level, and forwarding it unencrypted to the relevant endpoints.

Comment: @Morpheu5 thanks for getting back to me! Was that with nginx or haproxy?

Comment: @Chris that was nginx, no point in using haproxy as it does pretty much the same job and I was already using nginx.

Comment: @Morpheu5 Ok cool cool nice one. Yeah I'd prefer to do the same, just getting stuck on passing throuhg the ssl's without the lb needing its own certs. thanks

Answer (score 5):

The [`ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html) module is available as of Nginx 1.11.5 and seems to do just this.

It allows access to the SNI server name found in the client's `ClientHello` message via the `$ssl_preread_server_name` variable.

This information can be used to route a TCP ("stream") connection to a backend. The documentation for the module provides an example of how to do that.

Comment: Can you make this answer more complete despite the authoritative link?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers